# vue.js - v-on:change is not listening

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue.js version 2.5.17, and recently v-on:change is no longer working.

User clicks "choose files" button and on this change the image name should be captured. After this it will trigger the file or files to be displayed on screen and afterwards saved to firebase.

Instead I am now getting an error:

```
job.vue?d03e:825 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at eval (job.vue?d03e:825)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (_export.js?90cd:36)
    at VueComponent.uploadFile (job.vue?d03e:823)
    at VueComponent.uploadProofOfWork (job.vue?d03e:787)
    at click (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js?{"id":"data-v-45a8035d","hasScoped":false,"optionsId":"0","buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/job.vue (0.491509201fd57af656ef.hot-update.js:7), <anonymous>:1096:55)
    at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2027)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?efeb:1826)
```

The name property is found in the `fileUploaded` function attached to v-on:change.

Template:

```
<!-- DISPLAY IMAGES -->
<div class="job-images">
    <div v-for="(img, index) in this.job.images" :key="index" class="job-image-block">
        <img :src="img.url" :alt="img.name" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- REMOVE IMAGE BEFORE UPLOAD -->
<div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
    <a @click.prevent="removeImage(index)">X</a>
    <img :src="image.src" />
</div>
<!-- THE CHOOSE IMAGE BUTTON -->
<span class="input-group-text btn btn-primary btn-file" id="basic-addon2">
                        <input type="file" v-on:change="fileUploaded" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif"
                               name="input-file-preview" multiple/>
                      </span>
<div>
    <p>{{ loadingText }}</p>
</div>
<!-- UPLOAD IMAGE(S) BUTTON -->
<vue-button v-userRole.worker="{cb: uploadFile, role: job.role}" accent>
    <a @click.prevent="uploadProofOfWork()" style="color: white;">
                      {{ $t('App.job.uploadFileButton' /* Save Uploaded Images */) }}
                    </a>
</vue-button>
```

JS

```
uploadProofOfWork() {
        this.uploadFile().then(imageUrl => {
            this.data.image = imageUrl;
            db
                .collection("jobs")
                .where("taskId", "==", this.taskId)
                .add(this.data)
                .then(function(docRef) {
                    this.self.clearForm();
                    this.self.loadingText = this.$t(
                        "App.job.uploadedPhotoSuccessfully"
                    ) /* Post was created successfully. */ ;
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                });
        });
    },
    async uploadImages() {
        const self = this;
        const results = this.images.map(async({ file }) => {
        const imageUrl = await this.uploadFile(file, self.job.taskId);
        return { name: file.name, url: imageUrl };

        });
        Promise.all(results).then(async imageUrls => {
            if (!Reflect.has(this.job, "images")) this.job.images = [];
            const images = [...this.job.images, ...imageUrls];
            const result = await db
                .collection("jobs")
                .doc(this.job.taskId)
                .set({ images }, { merge: true })
                .then(docRef => {
                    console.log("updated!", docRef);
                });
        });
    },
    uploadFile(file, jobId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const self = this;
            const storageRef = firebaseStorage
                .ref()
                .child("jobs/" + jobId + "/" + file.name + "-" + uuid.v1());
            let uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);
            uploadTask.on(
                "state_changed",
                function(snapshot) {
                    const progress =
                        snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
                    self.loadingText =
                        this.$t('App.job.uploadedPhotoProgress') /* Upload is */ +
                        progress +
                        this.$t(
                            'App.job.uploadedPhotoProgress2'
                        );
                    /* % done. Processing post. */
                    this.upload.progress = (uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                    console.log(this.upload.progress);
                },
                function(error) {
                    reject(error);
                },
                async function() {
                    const downloadUrl = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                    resolve(downloadUrl);
                }
            );
        });
    },
    async fileUploaded(e) {
        const images = await Promise.all(
            Array.from(e.target.files).map(file => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = e => {
                        resolve({ src: e.target.result, file, progress: null });
                    };
                    if (e.target.file) {
                        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.this.file[0]);
                    }
                });
            })
        );
        this.images = images;
        console.log(this.images);
    },
```

Comment: I don't know how you use vue.js 3.0.1 because the last version is 2.5.17... Could you please copy here the whole stacktrace (e.g. on which line the error is thrown)?

Comment: @MátéWiszt, I've updated the post with your request. I also see what you mean about version. I thought `$vue --version` command gives the latest version, but it gave the vuex version. I checked in package.json and see vue version is actually `"vue": "^2.5.17"`.

Comment: the error doesn't have realtion to @change event, please provide the content of job.vue

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim, the template and js of job.vue is what is pasted above.

Comment: but you paste only the methods

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows the error occurs in `uploadFile`, called by `uploadProofOfWork`. The error is `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. The only reference to `.name` inside `uploadFile` is `file.name`, where `file` is a function argument. If you look in `uploadProofOfWork`, there are no arguments passed to `uploadFile`:

```
this.uploadFile().then(imageUrl => /* ... */)
```

It doesn't look like your code defines `file` anywhere in the path of `uploadProofOfWork`. I see `file` in `fileUploaded`, but it seems those files are intended to be uploaded in `uploadImages` (and not `uploadProofOfWork`). Perhaps your code is missing a separate file input for "proof of work".

Comment: do you mean like this: `        this.uploadFile(file).then(imageUrl => {` because that doesn't work.

Comment: I think the issue is far simpler than we thought: in uploadProofOfWork you call uploadFile but without any parameters despite the fact that you defined it with two parameters: file and jobId